# sinon-mongoose is not working with sinon 9

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

`sinon-mongoose = 2.3.0` is not working with `sinon 9`

My code is as below

```js
// test.js

const sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-mongoose');
const blog = require('../blog/blog.model');

it('GET Blogs /blogs/ls', (done) => {

    sinon
      .mock(blog)
      .expects('find')
      .chain('populate')
      .resolves([]);

    request(app)
      .get('/blogs/ls')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw done(err);

        done();
      });
  });
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'mock' of undefined
```

is there any other option or libs to mock model in mocha?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I gone through the issue in sinon-mongoose there is one fix but not published on npm so I directly used the fixed file. There is only one file.

Step to apply fix:

1. Download this file https://github.com/mir4ef/sinon-mongoose/blob/feature/sinon-v8-compatible/lib/index.js
2. Rename it `sinon-mongoose`
3. Import it from your local files into your test case.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('../sinon-mongoose');
```

4. it is working